# paypal payment standard in magento cart page?

Tags: magento, paypal, payment-gateway, shopping-cart

I need to integrate paypal payment standard in magento cart page. **I don't want to use express checkout.** Because it again redirects to magento site for billing information and order conformation.

Below process is my requirement:

1. user add a product to cart
2. User click the paynow button in cart page
3. User redirect to Paypal Login Page.
4. After User login with paypal, confirm and pay the amount.
5. User Redirect to magento thankyou page (order success page).

Is there any option in magento?

Answer (score 2):

Along with Payments Advanced and Payments Pro Magento does have a PayPal Standard option through the Community Edition. I was able to find a knowledge base article that walks you through setting up Payments Standard for Magento CE - http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-paypal-payments-standard-for-magento-community/